# Increase size limit for sql server Compact edition on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

Is there a way to increase the size limit for Sql Server Compact edition on Windows phone 7?
I am working on an app that adds a lot of data,and i keep getting size limit exception( size cannot be greater than 32Mb).

i tried adding "Max database size" to the connection string but it seems that doesn't work for Windows phone.
i have tried checking other peoples answer here but they dont seem to address windows phone

Comment: Ok,Thanks, it seems i didn't add the data source before the path to the file, when i did it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum database size of Windows phone7 sql server compact edition is 512 Mb;  You can refer to the following link to create a database of 512Mb

```
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202861(v=vs.92).aspx
```

MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext("Data Source = 'mydb.sdf'; File Mode = read only; Max Database Size = 512);

Comment: oh.. K. Refer the document for necessary changes.. Is my answer is helpful to you..?